# How to specify @ForAll non-zero integers?

Tags: java, jqwik

How can I specify `@ForAll` non-zero integers (i.e. either include both positive and negative integers, or exclude `0` from the integer range)? I couldn't find anything from https://jqwik.net/docs/current/user-guide.html#integer-constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I scrolled through the [User Guide](https://jqwik.net/docs/current/user-guide.html) a bit more, I got `@ForAll("nonZeroIntegers") int i` with the following to work (but I'm open to better solutions):

```
@Provide
Arbitrary<Integer> nonZeroIntegers() {
    return Arbitraries.oneOf(Arbitraries.integers().greaterOrEqual(1),
                             Arbitraries.integers().lessOrEqual(-1));
}
```